# Openshot distorted line on the right side after exporting

Tags: openshot

When I export a video using OpenShot 2.4.1, there is this distracting line on the far right side that is completely showing different thing from the actual video.

[image: screenshot of what it looks like]

It's like an overlay chaos. The line has moving video not in union with the rest of the video. I do not know why there is such.

Answer (score 0):

schauveau @ https://github.com/OpenShot/openshot-qt/issues/2053 precipitated my suspicion that it may be a combination of issues; I DO NOT KNOW as I haven't tested all of them, but I suspect it may be the width of the video not being divisible by 8 (e.g. 1280 yes, 1366 not) 1366 x 768 screens may be the root cause of the issue as well as the screen recorder.
It worked fine for me when using Simple Screen Recorder, I simply (pun intended) selected "Record a fixed rectangle" and changed the width to 1360 (divisible by 8) as opposed to 1366.

As schauveau stated, it appears that the last six pixels are the issue.

That was it.  Never use a preposition to end a sentence with.